# What changes occur in the system after a dev adds their own profile?

Tags: package-management, gentoo

I am working on building my own profile for portage.

I have managed to add my profile and it shows up when I issue:

```
eselect profile list
```

I added an entry in `/usr/portage/profiles`.
The profiles are of the directory pattern

```
architecture/profile_name/version/{stable, dev}/
```

What changes can I expect when I change this option and what is its purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, begin by reading the [Handbook:AMD64/Portage/Files](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Portage/Files) section.

Please understand that adding a profile is not a trivial task.  Portage profiles work on 3 Principles:

1. Variable/String Expansion - Provided by your Shell
2. Variable Inheritance/Hierarchy
3. USE Flags

**TL;DR:Skip to Wrap-Up**

Since most readers know what String Expansion is, we will skip that one, and start at Item 2. [Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29) creates the proper [hierarchical database model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_database_model), stored as text files in the `/usr/portage/profiles/` directory.

A few things to remember:

1. All Profiles follow standard portage behavior.
2. No profile in `/usr/portage/profiles` should be edited by hand, unless you are creating a new one.  All customizations to override a profile in use belong in `/etc/portage`.  If not, your customizations will be erased with every tree sync.
3. All Files contain standard Linux style comments indicating what a file is used for, and why each entry exists.
4. All profiles inherit items from the base profile. (Principle 2)
5. Since Gentoo is a rolling distribution, each of these files will contain a commit header.

   ```
   # Copyright 1999-2014 Gentoo Foundation.
   # Distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License, v2
   # $Header: /var/cvsroot/gentoo-x86/profiles/base/packages,v 1.67 2014/11/02 18:17:04 vapier Exp $

   # Gentoo Base Profile

   # NOTE: THIS IS THE BASE PROFILE FOR *ANY* GENTOO BASED OPERATING SYSTEM.
   # NO MODIFICATIONS MAY BE MADE TO THIS FILE WITHOUT PRIOR DISCUSSION.  IF
   # YOU ARE CREATING A NEW PROFILE, YOU SIMPLY NEED TO INHERIT THIS BASE
   # PROFILE IN YOUR PROFILE DIRECTORY'S "parent" FILE.

   # OK, you're staring at this file and you have no idea what these stars are
   # for.  Here's the scoop.  An initial "*" marks a package that is part of
   # the official BASE system profile.  If there is a "*" then `emerge system`
   # will use the line in its calculations of what should be installed for the
   # base profile.  Lines without a "*" prefix will be ignored for profile
   # system calculations.

   # Please note that this file is rarely used as a package inclusion mask
   # file, because it affects EVERY SINGLE gentoo profile.   As can be seen,
   # we've limited the inclusion mask to a version of portage which supports
   # cascaded profiles, but apart from that, there should be no version
   # specific information in here. This file serves as a high level description
   # of the minimum set of packages needed for any Gentoo based system.

   *>=sys-apps/baselayout-2
   *app-arch/bzip2
   *app-arch/gzip
   *app-arch/tar
   *app-arch/xz-utils
   *app-shells/bash
   #*dev-lang/perl
   #*dev-lang/python
   *net-misc/iputils
   *net-misc/rsync
   *net-misc/wget
   *sys-apps/coreutils
   #*sys-apps/debianutils
   *sys-apps/diffutils
   *sys-apps/file
   *sys-apps/findutils
   *sys-apps/gawk
   *sys-apps/grep
   *sys-apps/kbd
   # temporary bugfix for #398295
   *sys-apps/less
   # stopgap solution for functions.sh #373219 and #504116
   *sys-apps/openrc
   #*>=sys-apps/portage-2.0.51.22
   *sys-process/procps
   *sys-process/psmisc
   *sys-apps/sed
   *sys-apps/which
   #*sys-devel/autoconf
   #*sys-devel/automake
   *sys-devel/binutils
   #*sys-devel/bison
   #*sys-devel/flex
   *sys-devel/gcc
   *sys-devel/gnuconfig
   #*sys-devel/libtool
   #*sys-devel/m4
   *sys-devel/make
   *>=sys-devel/patch-2.6.1
   *sys-fs/e2fsprogs
   *virtual/dev-manager
   *virtual/editor
   *virtual/libc
   *virtual/man
   *virtual/modutils
   *virtual/os-headers
   *virtual/package-manager
   *virtual/pager
   *virtual/service-manager
   *virtual/shadow
   *virtual/ssh
   ```

---

Using the base profile as a start, we read:

> IF YOU ARE CREATING A NEW PROFILE, YOU SIMPLY NEED TO INHERIT THIS
>   BASE PROFILE IN YOUR PROFILE DIRECTORY'S "parent" FILE.

Using `amd64` as an example, I navigate to the parent file, and see:

```
../base
../../features/multilib/lib32
```

Hmmm, it looks as if a profile can inherit from more than one profile. As such, let's delve further into `../../features/multilib/lib32`.  Back in `/usr/portage/profiles`, we see a `features` directory.  This also happens to be two directories from our original `amd64` pofile.  Remember that `..` signifies the parent directory.  In the `lib32` directory of the `multilib` profile we find:

1. Another parent file, with the contents `..`
2. An eapi file
3. A `make.defaults` file

The parent file places us in the `multilib` directory, where we will begin inheriting USE Flags momentarily.  The eapi file contains 5, which signifies that we need a portage version that supports [Emerge API 5](http://devmanual.gentoo.org/ebuild-writing/eapi/), part of the [Package Manager Specification](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:PMS).  Knowing we need EAPI 5 tells us we need a [portage version >= 2.1.11.19](http://blogs.gentoo.org/zmedico/2012/09/20/official-eapi-5-support/).  Looking at the make.defaults file, we see:

```
# Copyright 1999-2011 Gentoo Foundation
# Distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License v2
# $Header: /var/cvsroot/gentoo-x86/profiles/features/multilib/lib32/make.defaults,v 1.2 2011/03/21 04:39:31 vapier Exp $

# Let baselayout create the lib symlink.
SYMLINK_LIB="yes"

# 32-bit LIBDIR
LIBDIR_ppc="lib32"
LIBDIR_x86="lib32"
LIBDIR_x86_fbsd="lib32"
LIBDIR_sparc32="lib32"
LIBDIR_s390="lib32"
```

---

Hmmm, it looks like that file manages the installation and upkeep of the libraries and the differentiation of `/lib32` and `/lib64` for each arch, using Principle 1.  If we follow the `parent` file back up to `multilib`, we see:

1. No Parent File, we must be in the right place to inherit USE Flags.
2. Another `eapi`, still containing 5.
3. Another `make.defaults` file
4. A `.force` file
5. 2 `.mask` files

   ```
   # Copyright 1999-2013 Gentoo Foundation
   # Distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License v2
   # $Header: /var/cvsroot/gentoo-x86/profiles/features/multilib/make.defaults,v 1.12 2014/03/27 01:55:29 vapier Exp $

   # Jorge Manuel B. S. Vicetto <jmbsvicetto@gentoo.org> (16 Nov 2011)
   # Rename STAGE1_USE to BOOTSTRAP_USE and stack it to the parent value
   # This is so we build with multilib from the start
   BOOTSTRAP_USE="${BOOTSTRAP_USE} multilib"

   # Default USE=multilib to on.  This rarely impact packages as they should be
   # using the multilib eclass anyways.  #435094
   USE="multilib"

   # FEATURES="multilib-strict" specific settings.
   MULTILIB_STRICT_DIRS="/lib32 /lib /usr/lib32 /usr/lib /usr/kde/*/lib32 /usr/kde/*/lib /usr/qt/*/lib32 /usr/qt/*/lib /usr/X11R6/lib32 /usr/X11R6/lib"
   MULTILIB_STRICT_DENY="64-bit.*shared object"
   MULTILIB_STRICT_EXEMPT="(perl5|gcc|gcc-lib|binutils|eclipse-3|debug|portage|udev|systemd|clang|python-exec)"

   # 64-bit LIBDIR
   LIBDIR_amd64="lib64"
   LIBDIR_amd64_fbsd="lib64"
   LIBDIR_arm64="lib64"
   LIBDIR_n64="lib64"  # MIPS n64
   LIBDIR_ppc64="lib64"
   LIBDIR_s390x="lib64"
   LIBDIR_sparc64="lib64"

   # 32-bit LIBDIR
   LIBDIR_arm="lib"
   LIBDIR_x86="lib"
   LIBDIR_x86_fbsd="lib"
   LIBDIR_o32="lib"    # MIPS o32
   LIBDIR_ppc="lib"
   LIBDIR_s390="lib"
   LIBDIR_sparc32="lib"

   # Somewhere in-between!
   LIBDIR_x32="libx32" # x86-64 x32
   LIBDIR_n32="lib32"  # MIPS n32
   ```

---

More variable setting and expansion (Principle one).  In the `.force` file we find:

```
# Copyright 2004-2014 Gentoo Foundation.
# Distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License, v2
# $Header: /var/cvsroot/gentoo-x86/profiles/features/multilib/package.use.force,v 1.1 2014/03/21 18:57:15 vapier Exp $

# These packages must have multilib turned on in order to work sanely.
sys-apps/sandbox multilib
sys-devel/gcc multilib
sys-libs/glibc multilib
```

This makes sense, the `multilib` profile needs these 3 packages to contain multilib symbols etc to build everything else.  In this instance `multilib` is a USE Flag (Principle 3).  In short, USE Flags and packages in this list are forced to use the settings in this file.  The forced settings are the USE Flags in parenthesis.

[image: Multilib Flag forcefully set]

---

The `.mask` files behave the same way.  For brevity's sake, I won't post it here. This leads us back to the base profile, where we will inherit the USE Flags in the `.force` files, the `make.defaults`file and the `.use` files.

### Wrap - Up

You inherit settings from the Arch Profile, and the Arch Profile inherits Settings from the Base profile.  See list below for order.

1. Settings from Make.defaults, USE Flags from the `.force` and `.use` files from the Arch chosen.
2. Settings from Make.defaults,  USE Flags from the `.force` and `.use` files from the base profile.
3. Settings from Make.defaults,  USE Flags from the `.force` and `.use` files from any other profile listed in the `parent` file.
4. Settings and USE Flags from `/etc/portage/make.conf`

To see all these settings in action, issue an:
`emerge --info`
which will expand most of the the variables and their values in each of these files.